# DLL hell - Could not load file or assembly System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, visual-studio-2019

I have very simple .NET Framework 4.7.2 app with the following nugets:

```
<packages>
  <package id="Autofac" version="5.1.2" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="DynamicData" version="6.14.8" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces" version="1.1.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="MSBuildTasks" version="1.5.0.235" targetFramework="net472" developmentDependency="true" />
  <package id="ReactiveUI" version="11.2.3" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Serilog" version="2.9.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Serilog.Enrichers.Process" version="2.0.1" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Serilog.Enrichers.Thread" version="3.1.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Serilog.Sinks.File" version="4.1.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Splat" version="9.3.11" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.Reactive" version="4.3.2" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" version="4.7.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions" version="4.5.3" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.ValueTuple" version="4.5.0" targetFramework="net472" />
</packages>
```

As you can see, there is `System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions` referenced in version `4.5.3` (I can't change this version, because other packages depend on it).

When I go to properties of this DLL reference in Visual Studio Solution Explorer, it shows version `4.2.0.1` referenced from `.....\packages\System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.4.5.3\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll`.

In `app.config` there is automatically generated binding redirect:

```
   <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.1" newVersion="4.2.0.1" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

When I run the app, I get exception:

[image: Exception message]

I already tried to change binding redirect to something like:

```
   <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-99.99.99.99" newVersion="4.5.3" />
```

But the issue persists. I have no idea how to resolve this dll-hell. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: The best way to surface the root cause of the failure is to enable the fusion log. I think "or one of it's dependencies" is the key phrase here, and you can see the actual missing file by checking the fusion log: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/fuslogvw-exe-assembly-binding-log-viewer

Comment: i tried to install this package, the default version of the  ``System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe`` it's ``4.5.2`` and not ``4.7.0``!!

Comment: When checked the 4.5.2 version of the assembly, I see an interesting assembly reference: `.assembly extern System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe`

Comment: The version numbers in `packages.config` are NuGet Package versions, and are not (necessarily) tied to the assembly version of the DLL within.  Have you tried removing that `<dependentAssembly>` node in its entirety?

Comment: Instead of using the packages.config file, you can also try to switch to PackageReference, which may or may not help, but is the new standard: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/migrate-packages-config-to-package-reference

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> When I go to properties of this DLL reference in Visual Studio
>   Solution Explorer, it shows version 4.2.0.1 referenced from xxxxxx

First, I think you have a little misunderstanding about the `DLL version` and `the nuget version`.

`version 4.5.3` is just the nuget package `System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions`'s version 
 number while `version 4.2.0.1` is just the `System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll`( exist in the nuget pacakge) number. They are not a concept at all. And you can see such dlls referenced in `xxx.csproj` file.

[image]

A version of the nuget package contains multiple competing DLLS for different project frameworks, which will be automatically installed into the corresponding project according to the nuget mechanism.

> DLL hell - Could not load file or assembly
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions

**As you said**, you have a nuget package called `System.Reactive version 4.3.2` that depends on `System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions 4.5.3` in your project. You can see this:

[image]

And from your error log, it seems that the project referenced `System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll 4.2.0.0` which it does not exists in the nuget package `System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions 4.5.3` and it should be `System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll 4.2.0.1`. Not sure if you changed the version number or the reason for the project.

You can check these steps:

**Solution**

**1)** make sure that `System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions` version is `4.5.3` in `packages.config` file.

**2)** make sure that you change the dll version to `4.2.0.1` in `xxx.csproj` file

**3)** Before you reinstall these, please [clean the nuget cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders) first, then run `update-Package -reinstall` under `Tools`-->`Nuget Package Manager`->`Package Manager Console` to reinstall the packages

**4)** create a new framework 4.7.2 project and then referenced these nuget packages to test whether it is caused by your project.

Comment: If I could upvote this 20 times, I would!

Comment: Do you have a blog? Where can I learn about this more?