# Could not load file or assembly System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions

Tags: c#, dll, nuget, visual-studio-2019, .net-assembly

Well I have a problem, we upgraded the .net framework from version 4.0 to version 4.6 of .net, I have about 9 projects running and I had to install masstransit and autofac in 2 projects, this caused some libraries to be updated or installed in other projects.

At the moment in one of the projects(Team.Services) I have installed the 4.5.2 version of the library System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions, before of this I had the version 4.2.0.0, but now I update this. The image below you can see that it is version 4.5.2.

[image]

Now when I see the references of the project I can see that I do not have the correct version referenced, it is as if another dll was installed

[image]

look for the solution(link below) in other places, also try to change the version in the app.config check the version in the package.config clear the nuget cache and reinstall everything. and it is not working, it keeps looking for the old dll and for this reason it doesn't find the new dll, besides the installations seem to be a different version.

[DLL hell - Could not load file or assembly System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60662705/dll-hell-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-threading-tasks-extensions)

This is the error:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException
  HResult=0x80070002
  Message=Could not load file or assembly 'System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
  Source=Team.Services
  StackTrace:
   at Team.Services.ServiceFactory.StartServices(String applicationDirectory) in C:\Users\amilkar.contreras\source\repos\TFS.TeamServices\Common\Team.Services\ServiceFactory.vb:line 110
   at Team.ServiceHost.Service.OnStart(String[] args) in C:\Users\amilkar.contreras\source\repos\TFS.TeamServices\Hosts\TeamServiceHost\Service.vb:line 25
   at Team.ServiceHost.Service.Start(String[] args) in C:\Users\amilkar.contreras\source\repos\TFS.TeamServices\Hosts\TeamServiceHost\Service.vb:line 34
   at Team.ServiceHost.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\amilkar.contreras\source\repos\TFS.TeamServices\Hosts\TeamServiceHost\Program.vb:line 41
```

Comment: Did you have a try to update the nuget pakcage to 4.5.3?

Comment: @DylanZhu-MSFT yes I try it

Answer (score 0):

You can have a try the possible solution to solve it:

1. Confirm the `Package Management` is `Package.config` in visual studio, then reinstall this package again
2. delete .vs folder then restart visual studio
3. Remove this dll manually, then add the new dll as reference manually